# Animating AutoLayout constrains breaks in iOS 9

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, ios9, ios-autolayout

So I just upgraded xCode to Version 7.0 (7A220) and it broke some animations, I'm not sure whats wrong here.

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:SLIDE_UP_DURATION animations:^{

    self.cubeIconWhiteYAlignmentToContainerView.constant = actualOffset;

    [self.cubeNoIconWhiteImageView layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.cubeIconWhiteImmageView layoutIfNeeded];

    self.buttonConstraintToBottom.constant = FINAL_BUTTON_HEIGHT;
    [self.logInButton layoutIfNeeded];
    [self.registerButton layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (finished) {
        [self fadeIn];
    }
}];
```

the buttons slide up just fine but the image views snap to their final height.  What am I missing is this just a bug on apples side?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So Apparently both views that the constraint touches need layoutIfNeeded called.